# Reconstruction on large sparse array

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I'm struggling with a reconstruction of a large sparse array. What I'm trying to do is to rearrange a 2 dimensional array (respresenting a system matrix for a given system of equations) such that I add up certain columns and rows and only take a submatrix of the original one.

**To be more specific:**

Let `Kmat` be a large sparse array with the dimensions 44000x44000.
The vectors `From1`, `From2` and `From3` give specific row/column numbers from where I want to take the values, which are added to the row/column numbers given in the vectors `To1`, `To2` and `To3`.
The dimensions of these vectors are much smaller, e.g. 300 to 400 entries.

Therefore, I want to perform:

```
(* adding rows *)    
Kmat[[;; , To1[[ ;; ]] ]] += Kmat[[;; , From1[[ ;; ]] ]];
Kmat[[;; , To2[[ ;; ]] ]] += Kmat[[;; , From2[[ ;; ]] ]];
Kmat[[;; , To3[[ ;; ]] ]] += Kmat[[;; , From3[[ ;; ]] ]];

(* adding columns *)
Kmat[[To1[[ ;; ]] ]] += Kmat[[From1[[ ;; ]] ]];
Kmat[[To2[[ ;; ]] ]] += Kmat[[From2[[ ;; ]] ]];
Kmat[[To3[[ ;; ]] ]] += Kmat[[From3[[ ;; ]] ]];
```

And then I only want to take a submatrix defined by the indices in the vector `take` with the dimensions around 43000:

```
Kmatnew = Kmat[[takes,takes]];
```

This all takes only about 0.1 seconds on my machine, which I would consider to be not expensive at all, but I repeat this a few thousand times which definitely adds up in my computation... I aim to do very efficient computing and that is definitely one of the bottlenecks of my code.

**My first idea:**

Try to use `Map` in some way, but I was not succesful in findiing a solution using `Map`...

**My second idea:**

Define a compile function with `Compile`, but unfortunately that does not work with sparse arrays.

I'd be very happy about some useful hints and ideas...

########################################

*Edit 25th July 2022: Add a small example to illustrate:*

Let's take an example in the dimensions 10x10:

```
dim = 10;
Kmat = Table[RandomInteger[10], {i, dim}, {j, dim}];
```

This results in e.g.

```
   Kmat = 
{{10, 10, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 2, 6, 6}, 
{7, 0, 5, 0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 6, 3}, 
{1,4, 3, 9, 8, 4, 8, 2, 5, 2}, 
{0, 5, 0, 5, 7, 3, 0, 8, 10, 0}, 
{10, 6, 1, 6, 7, 1, 5, 6, 0, 1}, 
{2, 9, 7, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 4, 9}, 
{5, 4, 5, 0, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 10}, 
{2, 9, 0, 3, 10, 1, 9, 10, 0, 8}, 
{0, 7, 4, 10, 5, 7, 8, 0, 9, 10}, 
{10, 10, 3, 9, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0, 4}};
```

We want to add the rows/columns in `From` to the rows/colums in `To`. Then, we take whats left if we leave out the `From`s.

```
To1 = {1, 3}; To2 = {2, 4}; To3 = {1};
From1 = {6, 8}; From2 = {7, 9}; From3 = {7};
Takes = Complement[Range[dim], Union[From1, From2, From3]];
```

Now we perform the upper procedure to add:

```
(* adding rows *)
Kmat[[;; , To1[[ ;; ]]]] += Kmat[[;; , From1[[ ;; ]]]];
Kmat[[;; , To2[[ ;; ]]]] += Kmat[[;; , From2[[ ;; ]]]];
Kmat[[;; , To3[[ ;; ]]]] += Kmat[[;; , From3[[ ;; ]]]];

(* adding columns *)
Kmat[[To1[[ ;; ]]]] += Kmat[[From1[[ ;; ]]]];
Kmat[[To2[[ ;; ]]]] += Kmat[[From2[[ ;; ]]]];
Kmat[[To3[[ ;; ]]]] += Kmat[[From3[[ ;; ]]]];
```

And this should result in

```
    Kmat = 
{{43, 38, 25, 17, 14, 11, 15, 12, 12, 25}, 
{19, 8, 18, 8, 12, 3, 4, 8, 8, 13}, 
{25, 30, 15, 17, 18, 5, 17, 12, 5, 10}, 
{18, 20, 12, 34, 12, 10, 8, 8, 19, 10}, 
{16, 11, 7, 6, 7, 1, 5, 6, 0, 1},
{15, 15, 15, 7, 5, 7, 6, 8, 4, 9}, 
{7, 5, 7, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 10}, 
{12, 18, 10, 3, 10, 1, 9, 10, 0, 8}, 
{15, 15, 4, 19, 5, 7, 8, 0, 9, 10}, 
{20, 19, 6, 9, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0, 4}}
```

Then, we take the `Take`s:

```
Kmatnew = Kmat[[Takes, Takes]];
```

and Kmatnew results in

```
Kmatnew = 
{{43, 38, 25, 17, 14, 25}, 
{19, 8, 18, 8, 12, 13}, 
{25, 30, 15, 17, 18, 10}, 
{18, 20, 12, 34, 12, 10}, 
{16, 11, 7, 6, 7, 1}, 
{20, 19, 6, 9, 1, 4}}
```

Sorry for the long post!

Comment: It's hard to say anything since we don't have your `SparseArray[]`. Could you consider using a matrix from e.g. `ExampleData["Matrix"]` as an example?

Comment: Hi, `ExampleData[{"Matrix", "685BUS"}]` looks similar to what I'm dealing with, only my matrix is much bigger. 
I also just fixed the numbering of the `From` vectors in my original post, since I falsely used `From1` in all lines. Please pardon me!

Comment: Could you actually give a small example with specific From and To lists. I think I get what you're saying, but it'd be nice to have a test case to verify against. So, like provide a starting matrix, a "from" list, a "to" list, and then the expected result matrix. It doesn't seem like the logic will depend on the fact that the array is sparse. It also seems like the last bit about a "take" list is separate, but maybe more concreteness there would help.

Comment: Hi, I just added a 10x10 example in the original post (see above), I marked the corresponding part with todays date. The idea/procedure is not depending on sparseness, as you said, but I suspect that the solution for speeding up this procedure might be... Thanks a lot for dealing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimers.** This answer comes with two disclaimers:

- I checked correctness only for the `dim=10` toy example given by OP. In the toy example, `Takes` is the complement of all `From`, and the `To` are contained in `Takes`, and so on. I do not know if that is supposed to be typical. Also, I have not clarified what exact assumptions one needs for this answer to give the correct result.
- I have not tested speed. Whether my approach is useful for OP in terms of speed could depend, for example, on how many nonzero the input matrix `Kmat` typically has, which OP has not specified. Without a typical example at hand, it did not seem a good idea to test speed.

**Answer.** Given `dim`, `From1`, `From2`, `From3`, `To1`, `To2`, `To3` and `Takes` we can define the following auxiliary sparse matrix

```
X = With[{To=Join[To1,To2,To3],From=Join[From1,From2,From3]},
        (SparseArray[MapThread[(List[##]->1)&,{To,From}],{dim,dim}]
           +IdentityMatrix[dim,SparseArray])[[Takes,;;]]
];
```

It should have on the order of `dim` many nonzero entries.

Then, given `Kmat`, we calculate the new matrix using two sparse matrix multiplications:

```
Kmatnew = X.Kmat.Transpose[X]
```

**Example.** As already mentioned, correctness was only checked in the `dim=10` toy example, and only for the particular `From1`, `From2`, `From3`, `To1`, `To2`, `To3` and `Takes` given by OP. In this case, the auxiliary matrix `X` is the sparse array version of

```
{{1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}
```

In this case the result is correct for all $10\times 10$ matrices `Kmat`.

Comment: Hi, your approach does the correct thing with my `Kmat`. My large sparse array `Kmat` has 996336 non-zero entries. The `AbsoluteTiming` of the reconstruction is reduced from 0.12 sec to 0.05 sec, which is a nice speedup! I was hoping to get it reduced to a negligible computation time, but perhaps that's too much to ask for since I'm dealing wth huge data... Your first point in the disclaimers is correct: The `Takes` is the complement of all equation numbers and the `From`s, the `To`s stay in the new matrix. Thanks a lot, @user293787!

Comment: @Frida Thank you for the feedback. That is only a moderate speedup. I am assuming that in your case `X` is always the same and only `Kmat` keeps changing. Perhaps one could exploit that, do some preprocessing on `X` and so on. But it is probably only worth doing if it is a bottleneck in your computation.